# How can I run a regression in R with a Pearson Type IV error distribution?

Tags: r

I have a set of 116 transcripts of speech that I've pulled word and unique word counts on using the Natural Language Toolkit.  When I attempt to run `lm()` regressions on them in R I'm getting some ridiculously non-normal error distributions, solidly in Pearson Type IV territory - kurtosis of 11, skewness of 1.5.  I've looked at the error histogram and qqplots, and the peak of the residuals is around -0.04, there's a noticeable dip around 0 on the qqplot, and there are some pretty monstrous outliers on the tails.  I'm not inclined to just chop a couple of outliers and have done, so is there a way of feeding a Pearson four-parameter error distribution into `glm()` or an equivalent to perform a regression?  I've resorted to the `heavy` library in the past when I had errors that were clearly t-distributed, but that doesn't handle Pearson.

Comment: You'd have to do some more generalized version of regression (`gamlss` `bbmle::mle2()`. `glm()` only takes distributions in the exponential family.

Comment: Have you looked at your input variables? Are they normally distributed? Could you for example log-transform them to be more normally distributed?

Comment: The distribution of the input variables should not matter to the distribution of the errors.  In any case, both the output variable and the key input variable (unique words in each transcript and the total number of words in each transcript, respectively) have already been log-transformed as the relationship between them is empirically known to be linear in the logarithms.

Comment: @BenBolker to my amazement it doesn't look like the gamlss.dist package includes the Pearson Type IV distribution as an option.